# How to move player along navmesh link's curve?

Tags: unity, navmesh

> NavMesh Link creates a navigable link between two locations that use NavMeshes.
>
> This link can be from point to point or it can span a gap, in which case the Agent uses the nearest location along the entry edge to cross the link.

I don't know why when I use [navmesh link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NavMeshLink.html) player move along horizontal plane (that I demonstrate it by red line) between gaps in navmesh link
Is there a option that player jump along curve (that I demonstrate it green curve)?
should I use force?

[image]

you can see player move horizontally! that isn't interesting.
[Offmesh Links - Unity Official Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w3-sSozYph4)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The navmesh links are curved only for visual fidelity.
In reality, they only store a start and end point (and some metadata).

If you want your agent to jump when encountering a link, you would need to do that yourself.
One way to do that is described in this [forum post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-trigger-a-jump-on-an-offmesh-link.313628/).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public enum OffMeshLinkMoveMethod {
   Teleport,
   NormalSpeed,
   Parabola,
   Curve
}

[RequireComponent (typeof (NavMeshAgent))]
public class AgentLinkMover : MonoBehaviour {
   public OffMeshLinkMoveMethod method = OffMeshLinkMoveMethod.Parabola;
   public AnimationCurve curve = new AnimationCurve ();
   IEnumerator Start () {
     NavMeshAgent agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> ();
     agent.autoTraverseOffMeshLink = false;
     while (true) {
       if (agent.isOnOffMeshLink) {
         if (method == OffMeshLinkMoveMethod.NormalSpeed)
           yield return StartCoroutine (NormalSpeed (agent));
         else if (method == OffMeshLinkMoveMethod.Parabola)
           yield return StartCoroutine (Parabola (agent, 2.0f, 0.5f));
         else if (method == OffMeshLinkMoveMethod.Curve)
           yield return StartCoroutine (Curve (agent, 0.5f));
         agent.CompleteOffMeshLink ();
       }
       yield return null;
     }
   }
   IEnumerator NormalSpeed (NavMeshAgent agent) {
     OffMeshLinkData data = agent.currentOffMeshLinkData;
     Vector3 endPos = data.endPos + Vector3.up*agent.baseOffset;
     while (agent.transform.position != endPos) {
       agent.transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (agent.transform.position, endPos, agent.speed*Time.deltaTime);
       yield return null;
     }
   }
   IEnumerator Parabola (NavMeshAgent agent, float height, float duration) {
     OffMeshLinkData data = agent.currentOffMeshLinkData;
     Vector3 startPos = agent.transform.position;
     Vector3 endPos = data.endPos + Vector3.up*agent.baseOffset;
     float normalizedTime = 0.0f;
     while (normalizedTime < 1.0f) {
       float yOffset = height * 4.0f*(normalizedTime - normalizedTime*normalizedTime);
       agent.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos, endPos, normalizedTime) + yOffset * Vector3.up;
       normalizedTime += Time.deltaTime / duration;
       yield return null;
     }
   }
   IEnumerator Curve (NavMeshAgent agent, float duration) {
     OffMeshLinkData data = agent.currentOffMeshLinkData;
     Vector3 startPos = agent.transform.position;
     Vector3 endPos = data.endPos + Vector3.up*agent.baseOffset;
     float normalizedTime = 0.0f;
     while (normalizedTime < 1.0f) {
       float yOffset = curve.Evaluate (normalizedTime);
       agent.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (startPos, endPos, normalizedTime) + yOffset * Vector3.up;
       normalizedTime += Time.deltaTime / duration;
       yield return null;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: @Seyed Morteza Kamali. Thank you, I forgot that links sometimes break.